# How create custom attribute handler for jsviews?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, jsrender, jsviews

I want to use JsViews to play html5 video content, like this:

**html:**

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <video autobuffer controls data-link="muted{:muted}">
        <source id="mp4" data-link="src{:src}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <button id="muted">change muted</button>
</script>
```

**js:**

```
var data = {
    src: "http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4",
    muted: true
};

var myTmpl = $.templates("#myTmpl");

myTmpl.link("#result", data);

$("#result").on("click", "#muted", function () {
    $.observable(data).setProperty("muted", !data.muted);
});
```

[example on jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ck9sr49L/2/)

As can be seen attribute `muted` processed by default and looks like `muted=true` or `muted=false`, but in HTML [specifications](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#attr-media-muted) - attribute "muted" may or may not be. That is, to should behave as an attribute of a `disable` here: [Data-linking the disabled and title attributes](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/attributes).

Maybe there is some way to customize(substitute) the standard html attribute handler in jsviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the muted attribute get removed when `muted` is `false`, by writing:

`<video autobuffer controls data-link="muted{:muted||null}">`

However that will not make things work as you want since the dynamically removing or adding the muted attribute will not actually mute/unmute the video control. To do that you need to set the muted property on the muted element to true/false.

Also when the user clicks on the built-in mute control on the video element UI, you want that to observably modify your `muted` data property. All that can be made to work with the following code:

```
var video = $("video");

$.observe(data, "muted", function(ev, eventArgs) {
    video[0].muted = eventArgs.value;
})

video.on("volumechange", function() {
    $.observable(data).setProperty("muted", video[0].muted);
});
```

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle, with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/ck9sr49L/3/.

I intend to add a new feature in the next JsViews to be able to choose to data-link to a property on an HTML element, rather than to the corresponding attribute. The syntax will be `data-link="prop-muted{:...}"` (similar to data-linking to a CSS property `data-link="css-muted{:...}"`). With that update you will be able to simplify things and write the following:

Template:

```
<video autobuffer controls data-link="prop-muted{:muted}">
    <source id="mp4" data-link="src{:src}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
<label>Muted: <input type="checkbox" data-link="muted"/></label>
```

Code:

```
var data = {
    src: "http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4",
    muted: true
};

var myTmpl = $.templates("#theTmpl");

myTmpl.link("#result", data);

$("video").on("volumechange", function(ev) {
    $.observable(data).setProperty("muted", ev.target.muted);
});
```